# MYSQL advise, table size

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database with client data, all client data is stored into a single table and are uniquely identified by a client code normalised into another table, eventually we will have 100+ clients all in the same table, each year the client data for every client will double, 1000+ rows of data a year per client.

what are the pros and cons of dividing each client into there own table and querying them by tablename instead of by client code, and will 100+ tables be unmanageable, and considering how much data we will eventually have is it even necessary to change anything ?

Comment: Are you worried about a couple thousand records after a few years? Seriously ;)  You know databases like MYSQL handle millions or records just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd question, but really I don't think you have anything to worry about, keep your database normalized (which you said you already do).

Leave it all in one table, it is a database, let it grow, don't worry that it will be 10k rows after 2-3 years.

I have dealt with large mysql/mssql installs and they work just fine on single servers with millions of records.

So no, don't break customers up into tables, it creates a management nightmare, stick to one, make it normalized and leave it be unless you run into problems.

**EDIT**

As you are still concerned, here is a direct copy from MYSQL:

> Scalability and Limits:
>
> Support for large databases. We use
>   MySQL Server with databases that
>   contain 50 million records. We also
>   know of users who use MySQL Server
>   with 200,000 tables and about
>   5,000,000,000 rows.
>
> Support for up to 64 indexes per table
>   (32 before MySQL 4.1.2). Each index
>   may consist of 1 to 16 columns or
>   parts of columns. The maximum index
>   width is 1000 bytes (767 for InnoDB);
>   before MySQL 4.1.2, the limit is 500
>   bytes. An index may use a prefix of a
>   column for CHAR, VARCHAR, BLOB, or
>   TEXT column types.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/features.html

Comment: (100 clients * 1000 rows) * 1 year = 100,000 rows a year, so in 5 years it will be half a million, is that a cake walk for MYSQL ?

Comment: ... yes not a problem.  If mysql had a limit of 1 million or 1/2 a million it would be a pointless db to use.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends entirely on how your data is structured.  If you have indexes on your table, things should remain reasonably fast even with millions of rows.  Separating the tables by client is not semantically "correct"...though depending on what data you are storing, it may be faster to store parts in various linked tables.  One table crammed with all the possible info you have might be a bit unwieldy just for the sake of easy querying.  Anyway, I could give a better answer if you post the actual table structure with a few rows of sample data, but the short answer is that so long as you treat the tables right (keep them normalized and clean), you should be fine.